# How to get images of cars samples for HaarCascade training?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on Opencv moving vehicle detection using opencv.
I need 2000 positive and 1000 negative samples of cars for detection.

Please give me some links where I can download car samples for deteciton.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll get far better results with Latent-svm detector. It already has a model for cars.

Comment: @GilLevi I had used Latent-svm model but it is very slow if we detect cars in video. It takes 10sec for each frame. so I moved on to HaarCascade which looks much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some useful links to dataset:
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/Data/Car/
http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/voc2007/
http://cbcl.mit.edu/software-datasets/CarData.html
http://www.emt.tugraz.at/~pinz/data/GRAZ_02/

OpenCV already have a trained xml file. You could make use of this if required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my dataset 3000 car positive samples from highway. Just like on image.

Follow the link to my blog [HERE](http://funvision.blogspot.cz/2016/11/computer-vision-car-dataset-for-opencv.html)

[image: Car dataset example]

Comment: Do you have negative samples that I can use? I just want to run through the exercise steps and have something working as a validation.

Comment: You can crop random images from your vacation as negative samoles. :)